# Replacing a set of strings containing any character

Tags: string, powershell, replace

Is there a way to replace a set of string no matter what the string contains?
I am trying to replace one string containing: quotes(""), brackets([]), @, e.

```
gci C:\test *.txt -recurse | ForEach {(Get-Content $_ | ForEach {$_ -replace '"my"', "money"}) | Set-Content $_ }
```

but what if a string I want to replace has EVERYTHING in <>:

```
PowerPlayReport Product_version="10.2.6100.36" xmlns="http://www.cognos.com/powerplay/report[1234@1]" Author="PPWIN" Version="4.0"
```

Comment: When you say _EVERYTHING in <>_ did you mean different characters since those dont appear in what I assume is your sample data. Did you perhaps mean `[]` or not copy enough?

Comment: Yes, but I just figured that I can use [regex]::Escape('  ')   So anything I enter inside the (' ') is ok.  My question now can you concatenate a string or string with new line? Example [regex]::Escape('My[text]') | `r`n more text

Comment: OK, but there should be more than that. I will make a small answer for you anyway

Answer (score 1):

So you want to replace everything in [] in the sample text you included in your question. If you were not aware ( although I think you are now ) `-replace` supports regular expressions. A simple regex can find the text you are looking for. I am also going remove some of the redundancy in your code.

```psh
Get-ChildItem C:\test -Filter *.txt -Recurse | ForEach-Object{
    $file = $_.FullName
    (Get-Content $file) -replace "\[.*?]","[bagel]" | Set-Content $file
}
```

Explanation borrowed from regex101.com

- `\[` matches the character `[` literally
- `.*?` matches any character (except newline). Quantifier: `*?` Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
- `]` matches the character `]` literally

So that line would then appear as the following inside the source file.

```
PowerPlayReport Product_version="10.2.6100.36" xmlns="http://www.cognos.com/powerplay/report[bagel]" Author="PPWIN" Version="4.0"
```

Comment: ok, Thank you! I'm running from command line, so can I run this from command line. I don't know how to create and execute a file yet.

Comment: @Alberto welcome to our site, make sure you mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the tickbox. It also doesn't hurt to upvote as well.